# How to use imagemagick to bulk crop images' whitespace just like the "trim()" of a string?

Tags: imagemagick

I have many PNGs uploaded by users.

However, they have white spaces around, which should be removed.

For instance:

An image like this:

[image]

Should be cropped to an image like this:

[image]

What should I do if I want to do this to all files matching `*_spec.PNG` files in a directory and all its subdirectories?

Example files:

```
Folder
 |
 Subfolder1 - file1_spec.png
            - file2_spec.png
            - file3.png
 |
 Subfolder2 - filea.png
            - fileb1_spec.png
```

I need to do this to these files:

- Subfolder1/file1_spec.png
- Subfolder1/file2_spec.png
- Subfolder2/fileb1_spec.png

Update:

1. OS: MacOSX Mojave 10.14.6
2. Imagemagick version: 7.0.10-22 Q16 x86_64 2020-06-27

Comment: Please state your operating system. Please give the full name of at least one file

Comment: Thanks, Mark, I have updated the information in the question.

Comment: Does it do what you want if you make a copy of an image and run `mogrify -trim IMAGE.PNG`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, exactly! Would you please teach me how to apply it to all the files in the folder with the pattern of `*_spec.png`? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make a COPY of your files in a spare directory before you do anything. Then go to the top directory and run:

```
find . -iname "*_spec.png" -exec mogrify -trim {} \;
```

Note that there are more efficient ways of doing this, but they are less readable and only really worth it if you have tens of thousands of files, or more. For anyone who's interested, that means using **GNU Parallel** and/or trimming more than one file per invocation of **ImageMagick** to better amortize the process creation time over multiple files.

Comment: I love that I can copy paste an answer and... it just works!